# Drawing the image of a complex map $z \mapsto 1/z$ with domain $\{z : \text{Re } z - \text{Im } z = 1\}$

Tags: complex-numbers, curves

I have to draw the image of the complex map $z \mapsto 1/z$ with domain $\{z : \text{Re } z - \text{Im } z = 1\}$

So, for $z = (y+1)+iy$, the function takes $z$ to $\frac{1}{(y+1)+iy}=\frac{(y+1)-iy}{|z|^2}$

So, clearly the image set is $\{z:\text{Re } z + \text{Im } z = 1/|z|^2\}$; and therefore I have to sketch $x+y = 1/(x^2 + y^2)$. While I was able to obtain the curve on Wolfram Alpha, I'm trying to understand how I can sketch this myself. Can I get any help?

**Edit (maybe a solution):**
Let $f$ be $f:z \mapsto1/z$, and let $w = u + iv = f(z) \implies z = 1/w$
Letting $z = x+iy$, I get 
$$x + iy = \frac{u}{u^2 + v^2}+i\frac{-v}{u^2 + v^2}$$
Since we know $x-y=1$
$$\implies \frac{u}{u^2 + v^2}-\frac{-v}{u^2 + v^2}=1 \implies u+v = u^2 + v^2 \\ \implies (u-1/2)^2 + (v-1/2)^2 = 1/2$$

Therefore, the image is $$\{w:|w-\frac{1}{2}(1+i)|=1/2\}$$

Is this correct? My first attempt was clearly incorrect

Comment: Hint: The function maps $z\mapsto \frac{\bar z}{|z|^2}$

Comment: Yeah, that's what I got. So, I'm guessing I'm scaling the conjugate? But still finding it a bit tough to sketch the image

Comment: I think I have a solution, please take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $z=x+yi$ and $x-y=1$, then $z=y+1+yi$ and$$\frac1z=\frac x{x^2+y^2}-\frac y{x^2+y^2}i=\frac{y+1}{(y+1)^2+y^2}-\frac y{(y+1)^2+y^2}i.$$The set of all these numbers is the circle centered at $\frac12+\frac12i$ with radius $\frac1{\sqrt2}$ (except for the point $0$).

Comment: Thanks! I just got it myself!

Comment: @junkquill I'm glad I could help.